# Characterization of $L^1(\text{SL}(3,\mathbb{R}))$

Tags: lie-groups, integration, haar-measure

Is there a characterisation of the integrable functions on SL($3,\mathbb{R}$) or an explicit expression for the Haar measure?

Comment: What do you mean by a characterization?? The integrable functions are the integrable functions!

Comment: As for your second question, does searching online not show you anything? Or looking in one of the many books that deal with analysis on (semisimple) Lie groups?

Comment: @YemonChoi I was thinking that maybe there is a way of viewing these functions as some (more explicit) class of functions on $\mathbb{R}^8$. As for the second question, I only found some expressions for the Haar measure in GL($n,\mathbb{R}$) but I don't know if it applies to SL. Which one of those many books do you recommend?

Comment: Since SL(3,R) is not homeomorphic to $R^8$ I am not sure why you want this. It sounds like you just want to know what the Haar measure is on SL(3,R) in terms of various standard parametrizations.

Comment: How about Varadarajan's _Introduction to Harmonic Analysis on Semisimple Lie groups_?

Answer (score 1):

The canonical reference is Knapp's book on semisimple lie groups, however, for Haar measure, the relevant part is dwelt at length in [Fuchs-Rivin](http://arxiv.org/abs/1506.01735) (no claims to originality, just to explicitness). Just as Yemon, I am not sure what the question is re integrable functions, but the magic term is "singular values".